# Последовательная асинхронная загрузка

Tags: jquery, javascript

мне передаётся объект с названиями скриптов, мне надо обойти в цикле все скрипты и подключить их последовательно.

```
$.each( data.scripts, function( i, script) {
    if(script.cache){                                         
        if(!$('#scripts').hasClass(script.name)){
          $.getScript('http://st.domain.su/js/'+script.name+'.js');     
        $('#scripts').addClass(script.name);
        }
    }else{
        $.getScript('http://st.domain.su/js/'+script.name+'.js');
        if(script.init){
            $.getScript('http://st.domain.su/js/'+script.name+'Init.js');
        }
    }

});
```

пока так, но получается что маленькие файлы загружаются первей, а большие позже. Но нередко бывает, что в больших стоит вызов на маленькие файлы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для jQuery 1.6+:

```
$.getScripts = function (files){
    var queue = $.Deferred().resolve();
    $.each(files, function (i, src){
        queue = queue.pipe(function (){
            return  $.getScripts[src] || ($.getScripts[src] = $.getScript(src));
        });
    });
    return  queue;
}

$.getScripts(['/js/foo.js', '/js/bar.js']).done(function (){
    console.log('All scripts loaded');
});
```

Comment: Что то не работает. Он говорит что всё загрузилось, но опть загружает в разном порядке

Comment: Не может быть, он загружает строго последовательно 
 1. FF - http://www.rubaxa.org/screenshot/9efeb6c46bf74b19a823b77e8d3d.png
 2. Chrome - http://www.rubaxa.org/screenshot/17cdc5884713205ce93060e78c58.png

Comment: Задача заключается в том, что пока не загрузится первый скрипт, не переходить к загрузке второго.

Comment: Они так и грузятся — http://www.rubaxa.org/screenshot/6d5bc39f737f8ce3c9ba0dba5808.png
Покажите лог— http://jsfiddle.net/hjwBc/

Comment: Да, всё верно. Просто чуть не так сделал. Спасибо.